# PHP exec() re-executing same script again and again

Tags: php, jquery, webserver, hosting, exec

Here I am writing about my flow in detail.

I am doing an Ajax request on same host.
AJAX call to `saveUser.php`

in `saveUser.php`, I have included `Common.php`.

`Common.php` have `createFile1()` and `createFile2()` function.

`createFile1()` function just creating a `sample1.php` for another purpose.

in `createFile2()`, I am creating a file `sample2.php` and executing a `exec('php /home/public/sample2.php > /dev/null &');` command to execute that file.

I am calling this `createFile1()` and `createFile2()` function respectively from `saveUser.php` which is being called by an AJAX request.

As I have set the exec command to run in background by '`&`' at end of command, it is returning without waiting for the response and all goes smoothly in front.

But when I am checking on my server, these files sample1.php and sample2.php are getting created again and again. It seems all this `saveUser.php` action are getting executed again and again until I stops the `sample2.php` process from SSH.

I checked the processes list, each time '`php /home/public/sample2.php`' is having `new process_id`, so it confirms that it is getting executed again and again. If I remove the `exec()` code and execute this sample2.php from SSH, it works as expected, there is not such problem.

Please suggest me whats going on wrong? Is there any problem with server configuration, I am using hostgator shared account.

Also I am including same `Common.php` file in `sample2.php` also, informing in case it can help it.

Thanks for your help in advance.

**saveUser.php code**

```
include_once dirname(__FILE__).'/Common.php';

createFile1();

createFile2();

echo 'saved successfully!';
```

**Common.php code**

```
function createFile1()
        {
                $template = file_get_contents('sendDmTemplate.php');

                $serviceFp = fopen('sendDmFiles/sample1.php',"w");
                fwrite($serviceFp , $fileContent);
                fclose($serviceFp);
        }

        function createFile2()
        {
                $fileContent = file_get_contents(dirname(__FILE__).'/sampleFileTemplate.php');

                $serviceFp = fopen('sample2.php',"w");
                fwrite($serviceFp , $fileContent);
                fclose($serviceFp);

                exec('php '.dirname(__FILE__).'/sample2.php > /dev/null &');
        }
```

**sample2.php code**

```
include_once dirname(__FILE__).'/Common.php';
echo 'hi';
```

Comment: Maybe try `include_once`/`require_once`?

Comment: Thanks David, I am using include_once for including any file.

Comment: Can you please check that there's no multiple AJAX calls on saveUser.php ?

Comment: Heh... I didn't really think it would be that simple, but you never know. I don't have much experience with `exec` or server config issues, so I doubt I can be much more help... sorry :-/

Comment: Oh, actually, @laurent has a point. Especially if you are triggering ajax with jQuery, it can be real easy to create multiple requests by accident. Check the network transmissions to see if you are sending more than one request.

Comment: I have checked the consol, it is not firing AJAX calls multitime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This exact same thing happened to me. I was trying to have one php script call exec() on another php script but for some strange reason it would just exec() itself again creating an infinite loop. The currently accepted answer didn't get me anywhere, but I was able to get it to work by specifying an absolute path to php.

So, instead of

```
exec('php /home/public/sample2.php > /dev/null &');
```

it would be

```
exec('/usr/local/bin/php /home/public/sample2.php > /dev/null &');
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the following:

1) Are you sure you are NOT calling your script saveUser.php multiple times? Mayby a codingerror somewhere in the javascript XHR? Check this by looking in the (apache?) log.

2) Are you sure your php executes alright without the -q? I use php -q pathtoscript.php

3) If not 1 or 2: Post the code in here (or somewhere) of saveUser.php

EDIT: I see your problem. The file you create includes common.php again, and executes that again. Etc. <-- wrong Oops. I wrote that too early. Looking into it again now.

4) Is it possible you use some errorhandling that redirects to your saveUser.php?

Edit:

5) There might arise a problem from the fact that you are including the file that is executing the command itself in combination with include_once, but I am not sure. You could simply test this by changing your content of sample2.php content by adjusting sampleFileTemplate.php. Create a common2.php (with identical content as common.php), and use that one. COuld you testdrive that setup and report back?

Comment: Hi Erwin, checked access log, there is not any problem of multiple request. also tried using -q, it's also not solving the problem. I am pasting my code in the  question itself. wait.

Comment: Hi @Erwin, Updated the code in question, Please have a look at it.

Comment: Hi Erwin, but the code in Common.php is in functions, so function should not be called automatically, isn't it?

Comment: Sorry Erwin, It is also not the case. Can there be any file permission issue? I have contacted hostgator support, waiting for their response.

Comment: Please post your answer back if you found the reason. I am curious.

Comment: Hi Erwin, it didn't solved problem, If I am running the script from CLI, it's working good, let me wait till Hostgator Support team reply me. Thanks Erwin for your support. Will let you know once I get some solution.